# serialization issue with json structure using newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net

This is an old application (.Net 4.5).

I am following the guide here: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/aug/30/using-jsonnet-for-dynamic-json-parsing

My goal is to have a way to store a flexible json structure without tying it down to a static structure. For example, in the TriggerJson below, the actual Trigger field is of type string, which is supposed to be json. That json structure could reflect ExpiryTriggerJson, or some other structure which is determined by TriggerType.

I have the following structure:

```
public class TriggerJson
{        
    public string TriggerType { get; set; }        
    public string ConfiguredBy { get; set; }
    public string Trigger { get; set; }
}

public class ExpiryTriggerJson
{
    public string ActionType { get; set; }
    public TriggerRecipient[] Recipients { get; set; }
}

public class TriggerRecipient
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsTag { get; set; }

}
```

In the following code, I am creating a list of TriggerJson such that each element's Trigger field be a json structure made from ExpiryTriggerJson object:

```
            var tjList = new List<TriggerJson>();
            var triggerJson = new TriggerJson();
            triggerJson.TriggerType = TriggerJsonHelper.ExpiryTriggerType;
            triggerJson.Trigger = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new ExpiryTriggerJson
            {
                Recipients = taskRecipients,
                ActionType = TriggerJsonHelper.ExpiryTriggerActionType_Task
            });                    
            triggerJson.ConfiguredBy = configuredBy;
            tjList.Add(triggerJson);
            fieldValue.TriggersJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tjList);
```

This creates the following structure for example where Trigger field reflects a serialized structure which has escaped double quotes due to double serialization:

```
[{"TriggerType":"ExpiryTrigger","ConfiguredBy":"acd1ac353ac44e078aaef8ce6479a4c6","Trigger":"{\"ActionType\":\"CreateReminderTask\",\"Recipients\":[{\"Id\":\"70050a95-f31b-41b7-9b49-0688fa76dba5\",\"Name\":\"blah blah\",\"IsTag\":false}]}"}]
```

This creates a problem for me when trying to deserialize this data later on when reading it back:

```
JArray jsonObj = JArray.Parse(triggersJson);
            foreach (dynamic obj in jsonObj)
            {
                if (obj.TriggerType == ExpiryTriggerType)
                {
                    ExpiryTriggerJson triggerData = obj.Trigger.ToObject<ExpiryTriggerJson>();
```

The above code tries to parse back ExpiryTriggerJson structure that was first assigned to the field Trigger of TriggerJson element. This throws a runtime deserialization exception when executing the last line trying to convert to ExpiryTriggerJson which I suspect happens due to double deserialization.

My question is how do I accomplish my goal of storing static/structural json data as a string and then parse it back in a nested manner?

Comment: Try storing your dynamic json property as JToken (JObject, JArray).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you want.

```
public dynamic Trigger {get;set;}
```

Then trigger will be resolved to whatever type it receives at runtime.